# Paperclip saves images but doesn`t show it in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I was using Paperclip for almost a month and it worked well. After some fixes in config and preparations for test it fell off and now it is saving images properly, but shows something like '%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83_%D0%B7_2016-06-28_11-35-01' instead of picture itself. All the pictures are uploaded from form by file field tag. Can you please tell me how to fix this or advise a guideline to mend such kind of stuff? 
**My model:**

```
class Initiative < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 3
  include InitiativeStates

  scope :searched, ->(query) { where('title LIKE ?', "%#{query}%") }

  resourcify

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :timelines
  has_many :initiative_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :initiative_categories, class_name: 'Category'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :initiative_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

  has_attached_file :main_image,
                    path: ':rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
                    url: '/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
                    default_url: ':rails_root/public/default/def.phg'

  validates :title,
            presence: true
  validates :short_description,
            length: { maximum: 200 },
            presence: true
  validates :needed_sum,
            inclusion: 100..50_000

  validates_attachment :main_image,
                       content_type: { content_type: %w[image/jpeg image/gif image/png] },
                       presence: true
end
```

**Main view:**

```
<div class="initiatives">
  <div class="row">
    <%@initiatives.each do |initiative| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <%=render 'shared/short_view_initiative', initiative:initiative %>
        </div>
        <%= %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

**Partival for initiative:**

```
  <div class="initiative">
      <%=link_to initiative_path(initiative) do%>
          <div class="frame">
            <%= image_tag initiative.main_image(:medium), class: 'initiative-image' %>
          </div>
      <%end%>
      <div class="initiative-title">
        <strong><%=initiative.title%></strong>
      </div>
      <div class="initiative-short-description">
        <p><%=initiative.short_description %></p>
      </div>
      <% if user_signed_in? && (current_page? user_show_initiatives_path(current_user))%>
          <div class="initiative-state">
            <b><%=find_out_initiative_state(initiative)%></b>
          </div>
      <%end%>
    </div>
```

**Part of controller:**
    class InitiativesController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @initiatives = Initiative.approved.order('approved_at ASC').page(params[:page])
  end
end
```

I have created a proper migration for it and all the preparations were done and everything worked. Also img tag links lead to the proper destination where these files are, but it does not render the images.

Comment: Can you please show your carrierwave initializer file, also share action, model on which carrierwave is applied and the view from which the problem arises.

Comment: Well I would say show us your relevant view, model, and tell us what steps you took to integrate paperclip,  and basically show us more data from your app that paperclip is connected to. We cannot know what your app looks like!!! And also please tell us what you have tried so far

Comment: Hey, I edited that.